# spring rest api for file download design best practice

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-rest

I have to work on POC where we will have data stored in some kind of NOSQL db. Initial load of the data in this db would be around 100M and it will grow 10M every year. Now requirement is that I have to provide two apis. One with simple look up by some unique id. This is straight forward. Second api is about client will send request with say for eg. 10K unique ids and then api should deliver file(JSON data) to the client.
What is the best practice around developing rest api like this? Does it even make sense to have api?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best practice around developing rest api like this?

If I understood the requirement, I would do:

For single insert:

HTTP POST /objects

Content-Type: application/json

Data:

```
{
    "some_property":"value1",
    ...  others properties here
}
```

Response: Created 201

Location: /objects/{unique_id_generated}

For bulk insert:

HTTP POST /objects/bulk

Data:

```
[
{
    "some_property":"value1",
    ...  others properties here
},
... others objects here
]
```

Response: 201 Created

Location: /objects/bulk/{unique_id_bulk_insert}

Get info about bulk insert:

HTTP GET /objects/bulk/{unique_id_bulk_insert}

Data response:

```
[unique_id_1, unique_id_2, ... N ids generete by bulk insert ]
```

Retrieve the object by id:

HTTP GET /objects/{unique_id_generated}

Data response:

```
{
    "some_property":"value1",
    ...  others properties here
}
```

Retrieve an object list by parameters defined in requirements:

HTTP GET /objects?some-filter=...

Data response:

```
[
{
    "some_property":"value1",
    ...  others properties here
},
... others objects here
]
```

> Does it even make sense to have api?

I think yes, depending of the requirement, and the necessities of project, yes make sense.

Comment: Thanks Bruno for your response. Inserting data api in not what I was asking. I was asking for GET api to search data from elastic search for about 10-15K unique ids and return those json documents as single file. Since look up for these many unique ids will be slow, does client suppose to wait that long? If I have to make this call asynchronous, how that should work?

Comment: Sorry my mistake! Asynchronous in this case is good. Generate an id of request and than client get info about the search. Other way, in the request, client pass the url/resource for your service notify when finished job.